# Trying to efficiently parallel process some data from a File Stream in .NET (read -and- write)

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, stream, async-await

I'm trying to see how to efficiently read in some data from a file, do some parallel work (per line) then write the new line back to the file system.

I know I can do this, one line at a time .. but I was hoping to do this a few lines at a time -or- .. if one line is 'busy' waiting for the async work to complete, then move on to the next line, etc.

Here's some sample data and logic...

```
Header
SomeId#1, SomeId#2, SomeId#3, Name, Has this line been processed and cleaned(true/false)

File Data
444,2,12,Leia Organa, true
121,33333,4,Han Solo, true
1,2,3,Jane Doe, false
1,4,11,John Doe, false
```

So the first 2 lines have been processed and I will skip those lines.
The 3rd and 4th line need to be processed. When the data has been checked, I wish to save this back to the file like

```
1,33333,3,Jane Doe, true
```

So this is the general logic...

- read line
- call `DoWorkAsync()` <-- which could take a second or 5
- save this line back to the file again.

I was just hoping that I didn't have to wait for the `DoWorkAsync()` to complete before I can save then read the next line. I was hoping that I could start reading the next line ... and if the previous line finishes .. fine .. then save that line to the same line number in the file .. and move on again to the next line.

It's like I could have 5 or 10 lines all working at the same time .. waiting for the results to come back from the 3rd party api ... working in parallel or whatever.

Can this be done in .NET? I'm sure .NET has the functionality for this .. I just can't see the pattern to do this.

NOTE: I usually do async/await for I/O intensive operations (like hitting the filesystem or calling some 3rd party api endpoint) vs Parallel.ForEach which I use for cpu intensive work.

NOTE: Why the `true/false` at the end of the line? Because I can't process all the lines at once. I have api limits.

Other ideas were to have two files, one for PENDING and one for PROCESSED.

Comment: well ... if you're updating the file, you'll have to re-read it ...won't you? what's wrong with loading all lines to memory (using a poco with id = line_number, val = line, bool = status), updating that, and writing it once back (avoiding reading and writing the same file over and aver ?

Comment: i was trying to see if I could do this with a low mem footprint. Sure I could load the whole file in. I have about 3.6 millions lines though (as of right now).

Comment: good start ... 3.6M ... looks like it's gonna suck either way ... i don't see how you'll do the reading/updating at the same time TBH ... I'd probably break it into either multiple files, or simply output to partial files and then recompile them back, but maybe somebody else have an idea :)

Comment: heh @ multiple files -> i just made a comment about that in the OP :)

Comment: I do not think there is an easy way to write only parts of the file without overwriting it entirely (e.g. no easy file "random access"). Maybe if you do not change the byte length of the file you could use some sort of stream to write into specific positions, but it appears truly difficult to me to do this kind of work in parallel.

Comment: You need a read and write buffer, per-line. Read as many lines as you can process in parallel, and write them out in the correct order when they are done. If you want to keep things simple, batching will work fine and isn't too hard to implement with await/async. And yes, you most likely want the output file to be different - there's no way to insert text in the middle of a text file. There's a reason text files are only used for interchange and not data storage :)

Comment: One important requirement fact is missing; is the order important? If the exact order is important then you would really need to have a queue batching for the writing (i.e. a sequential writer). My suggestion; rename original file first, read x lines, do async operation on the lines, maybe using Parallell.For, and write the finished lines to the original file name using a single thread writer (to avoid two writing operations at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a stub of a parallel processor which uses `async`/`await` while processing lines in batches.

This approach ensures that the same order is preserved when writing.

```
public async Task ProcessFile()
{
    const int parallelism = 5;

    using (var readStream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\myinputfile"))
    {
        // put HERE your logic for skipping to a specific line
        // e.g. readStream.Seek(lastPosition); 

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(readStream))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

                for (var i = 0; i < parallelism; i++)
                {   
                    var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

                    tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(line));

                    if (reader.EndOfStream)
                        break;
                }

                var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

                using (var writeStream = File.Open(@"d:\myresultfile", FileMode.Append))
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
                {
                    foreach (var line in results)
                        await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public async Task<string> DoWorkAsync(string line)
{
    await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(1000, 5000));
    // do some work and return line with last parameter = true
    return line.Replace("false", "true"); // e.g.
}
```

It surely needs improvement, but it should give you a good base for writing your own.

Comment: good base work but I still don't see how he gets around the problem of appending, which will write the lines to the END of the file. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx):  ``` 
Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or creates a new file. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Append permission. FileMode.Append ... Trying to seek to a position before the end of the file throws an IOException exception, and any attempt to read fails and throws a NotSupportedException exception.```

Comment: @Noctis may you elaborate further? This method just writes (appending) to another file (unrelated with the input file), there is no need to seek the output file while writing new rows. I didn't find any reliable method for reading and writing the same file without overwriting it at every write.

Comment: yep, that's what i was saying, you output to different files , not reading and writing to the same file... we're on the same page.